# rxjava merge observables of different type

Tags: asynchronous, observable, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to rxjava. I need to combine two observables that emit objects of different type. Something like `Observable<Milk>` and `Observable<Cereals>` and get a `Observable<CerealsWithMilk>`. I couldn't find any operator for something like this. What would be the rx way of doing something like this? Note that `Milk` and `Cereals` are async.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you need, but possibly [zip()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(rx.Observable,%20rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2)) or [combineLatest()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#combineLatest(rx.Observable,%20rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2)).

`zip` will take both `Observable<Milk>` and `Observable<Cereals>` and let you combine them into `CerealsWithMilk` via a provided function.  This emits a new `CerealsWithMilk` each time you get get **both** a `Milk` **and** a `Cereals`.

`combineLatest` is similar to `zip` except it will emit a new `CerealsWithMilk` even if **just** a new `Milk` **or** just a new `Cereals` is emitted.

Comment: Note - (so long as each of the source Observables has emitted at least one item).

Comment: when `zip` operator used, the problem is the observable results are waiting to each other. In fact I am wanting to use as soon as finished Observable. 

can 'combineLatest' operator satisfy my needs?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to merge observables of different type you need to use  [`Observable.zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html):

```
Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("a", "b", "c");
Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Observable<String> result = Observable.zip(o1, o2, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

`result` will be an observable generating the application of `(a, b) -> a + b` to `o1`'s and `o2`'s items. Resulting in an observable yielding `"a1", "b2", "c3"`.

You can use any function. For example

```
    Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("a", "b", "c");
    Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
    Observable<String> result = Observable.zip(o1, o2, (a, b) -> myFunc(a, b));
    //...

    private String myFunc(String a, Integer b) {
            //your code here
            return someString;
        }
```