# How do I join two RxJava2 Obvervables by key?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I have two unsorted observables of different types. Both of these types share a common key. I'd like to join them into a new observable emitting pairs of corresponding elements and I can't figure out how to do it.

Note that some of the keys might be missing. It would be OK if not complete pairs are dropped, but having `null` in place of missing piece would be even better.

Input 1:

```
Entity(id = 2),
Entity(id = 1),
Entity(id = 4)
```

Input 2:

```
Dto(id = 3),
Dto(id = 2),
Dto(id = 1)
```

Expected output (in any order):

```
Pair(Entity(id = 1), Dto(id = 1)),
Pair(Entity(id = 2), Dto(id = 2)),
Pair(null, Dto(id = 3)),
Pair(Entity(id = 4), null)
```

Comment: How long would you want the Observables to wait for their corresponding element?

Comment: Indefinitely I guess. The entities come from the DB and Dtos are from Http request so I should have the full data set in memory

Comment: If that's so, why do streaming at all, might be a lot easier converting them to in memory collections and doing the transformations then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220050/rxjava-merge-observables-of-different-type - Sort them first, zip them after, call an action of both which combines them.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold This wouldn't work as the keys are missing - unless I'm missing something ofc.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz To be honest I've expected this answer :D I think I just needed to hear it from someone more experienced in Rx

Comment: Kacper, it does. Sort it by Key, the data with the missing key goes to the end and. Means if you combine them "entity 1, entity 2, dto 3, entity 4, dto 5, entity null, dto null, entity null,  ...  But i think even if you can solve this, this doesnt seems like a legit design pattern

Comment: Protip: If you have to wait indefinitely for something, streaming can't help you. :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220837/full-outer-join-of-two-ordered-observables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Observable.merge` the streams together: this gives you a stream of all the items. (In the code below, I've used a custom `Either` class to tag each stream.)

Then, for each item in the stream, try to match it with a previously-observed item of the other type, and output the pair. If not, save it to be matched later.

Finally, once the stream is done, the remaining unmatched elements won't be matched with anything, so they can be emitted unpaired.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable

data class Entity(val id: Int)
data class Dto(val id: Int)

sealed class Either<out A, out B>
data class Left<A>(val value: A) : Either<A, Nothing>()
data class Right<B>(val value: B) : Either<Nothing, B>()

fun <A : Any, B : Any, C> joinById(a: Observable<A>, idA: (A) -> C, b: Observable<B>, idB : (B) -> C): Observable<Pair<A?, B?>> {
    val unmatchedA = mutableMapOf<C, A>()
    val unmatchedB = mutableMapOf<C, B>()
    val merged = Observable.mergeDelayError(a.map(::Left), b.map(::Right)).flatMap { latest ->
        when (latest) {
            is Left -> {
                val id = idA(latest.value)
                unmatchedB.remove(id)?.let { return@flatMap Observable.just(latest.value to it) }
                unmatchedA.put(id, latest.value)
            }
            is Right -> {
                val id = idB(latest.value)
                unmatchedA.remove(id)?.let { return@flatMap Observable.just(it to latest.value) }
                unmatchedB.put(id, latest.value)
            }
        }
        Observable.empty<Nothing>()
    }
    return Observable.concat(merged, Observable.create { emitter ->
        unmatchedA.values.forEach { emitter.onNext(it to null) }
        unmatchedB.values.forEach { emitter.onNext(null to it) }
        emitter.onComplete()
    })
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val entities = Observable.just(Entity(2), Entity(1), Entity(4))
    val dtos = Observable.just(Dto(3), Dto(2), Dto(1))
    joinById(entities, Entity::id, dtos, Dto::id).blockingForEach(::println)
}
```

```
(Entity(id=2), Dto(id=2))
(Entity(id=1), Dto(id=1))
(Entity(id=4), null)
(null, Dto(id=3))
```

Note that this may have some odd behavior if the ids are repeated within a stream, and depending on the structure of the streams it's possible that this will end up buffering a lot of elements in memory.